# writing template for operator<< for any vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to write a template operator for any iterable container.  Getting a strange error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

> vec.cc:5:6: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with
>   operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'const
>   char [2]')   os << "[";   ~~ ^  ~~~

Why this error?  And how do I achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Curious sorry, fixed.

Comment: @tobi303 fine, I added #include

Comment: @MK. well, its still just a template but nothing that will ever be executed. At least you need to instantiate it

Comment: I think this operator at global level can generate ambiguity with a lot of types. operator << (stream, something) is almost the definition of the operator << for a stream

Comment: @StefanoBuora is there a way to say that I want to define it for any, say, vector?

Comment: @tobi303 I will try instantiating it once it compiles.

Comment: I would try to use some SFINAE rule (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Changing the prototype accrodling can make the trick

Answer (score 9):

Adding

```
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

Conflicts with the other [global overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of `operator <<`.

To fix this we can constrain your template to any vector instead of any type using

```
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<C>& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

At this line:

```
os << "[";
```

The compiler finds **two** valid functions: the STL's and yours.

You need to be a bit more specific in your template declaration in order to resolve the conflict:

```
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<C>& c) {
  ...
```

Expanding this to containers in general would require a bit of finagling with `std::enable_if<>` that will probably just confuse you further. I recommend you just add an overload for each type of container you want to support.

**Edit:** Also, overriding  `ostream << T`, for types you don't own is generally a bad idea as it will eventually cause conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because your function matches every call to `<<` with a `std::ostream&` on the left.

> ```
> template <typename C>
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
>   os << "[";
>   for (const auto& v : c) {
>     os << v << " ";
>   }
>   os << "]";
>   return os;
> }
> ```

When you write `os << "["`, the compiler finds multiple `operator<<` functions to call; your's is one of them. By adding a global `operator<<` that's templated to take any type, you intercept basically every call to `operator<<`.

The cleanest way you could do this is to define a new function, say `print_collection`:

```
template <typename C>
void print_collection(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
}
```

If you *really* want to define an `operator<<`, this gets more tricky. You could do this:

```
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<C>& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

However, if the standard library decides to add an `operator<<` of their own for `std::vector`, your code will break.

I'd strongly recommend that if you wanted to add such an `operator<<`, you do it for your own type. Something like this:

```
template <typename Iter>
class Range {
    Iter begin_;
    Iter end_;

public:
    Range() = default;
    Range(Iter begin, Iter end)
        : begin_{ begin }
        , end_{ end }
    {}

    auto begin() const { return begin_; }
    auto end() const { return end_; }
};

template <typename Iter>
auto range(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    return Range<Iter>{ begin, end };
}

template <typename C>
auto range(const C& collection) {
    return range(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection));
}

template <typename Iter>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Range<Iter>& range) {
    os << "[";
    for (const auto& v : range) {
        os << v << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec = ...;
std::cout << range(vec);
```

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because your `operator<<` matches a lot of other overloads in the standard library.  In your case with the overload meant to go with `const char[2]`.

If you want this to work with any iterable container, one way is to constrain it to check for the validity of `begin()` and `end()` methods on it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename Container,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().begin()),
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().begin())>::value>* = nullptr>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Container& container) {
    os << "[";
    for (const auto& ele : container) {
        os << ele << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    auto vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
    cout << vec << endl;
}
```

Comment: Seems you've typed `begin` twice.

Comment: _check for the validity of begin() and end() methods on it_ ... it's not a requirement for a container to provide *members* `begin()` and `end()` to be iterable.

Comment: @zett42 it's a requirement for range based for loop, which this code uses.

Comment: @zett42 ah nevermind, it's a requirement that `std::begin` and `std::end` works.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan no I have not, the return type of `begin()` and `end()` does not have to be the same and therefore I have only checked for `begin()`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I could not check for `std::begin` and `std::end` because that works for regular arrays as well and will cause a conflicting overload

Comment: [It will also create conflicts for things like `std::vector<std::string>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e2aee8c9016333a).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your definition of the operator << is causing an ambiguity with the standard operator defined for a C++ stream.

I'd try to use some SFINAE technique changing your prototype in something like:

```
template <typename C>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c, C::const_iterator fakeVar = c.begin() ) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

It should make your template suitable only if it can be compiled

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, for `os << "["` your operator introduce an ambiguity.

I don't know if it's a good idea but I propose the use of SFINAE to enable your operator only for types supporting `begin()`.

I mean

```
template <typename C>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c)
   -> decltype( c.begin(), os ) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto & v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: _I don't know if it's a good idea but I propose_ ... why do you even write this then?

Comment: what is this -> decltype syntax?

Comment: @zett42 - I don't know if it's a good idea redefine `operator<<` for generic containers

Comment: @MK - do you mean `auto [...] -> decltype()` or the comma trick inside `decltype()`?

Comment: @MK. - are two different things; `auto [...] -> type` is a new C++11 way to define the return type of functions; in this case the type is `decltype( os )`, that is "the type of `os`", that is `std::ostream &`. You can ask: why don't you simpli write `std::ostream &` instead of `auto` (etc.). Answer: because I want use SFINAE (substitution failure isn't an error). (continue)

Comment: @MK. - The comma trick in `decltype()` is put `c.begin()` before the comma. If `c` support `begin()` (case `std::vector`, by example), there isn't a failure, the comma discard `c.begin()` and `decltype()` evaluate `os` and the operator is implemented. If `c` doesn't support `begin()` (`char[2]`, by example), failure and the `operator<<` isn't implemented (without error).

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity comes from the fact that your template overloads the `operator<<` for the `std::ostream` and multiple definitions can be used.

Practically, for example, the standard library defines:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);
```

Your function will match the same with template substitution `typename C = const char*`.

In order to solve this ambiguity you can either adopt another design choice (for example, avoid to overload `operator<<`) or solve the ambiguity specialising the template function.

Many other answers can be good in that context, I'd suggest you another option (quite less verbose, but with some limitations. See below).

Since you're trying to print *Containers*, it's likely that a container is a template class (`std::vector<T>`, `std::list<T>`, etc...). So your function can be slightly modified in order to handle only types which are template classes.

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class Container, typename T,
          typename... Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Container<T, Args...>& c) {
  os << "[";
  for (const auto& v : c) {
    os << v << " ";
  }
  os << "]";
  return os;
}
```

Note that code will requires *C++11* because of *variadic templates*.

[Here](http://ideone.com/QqaXtM) an example to show that ambiguity has been solved.

Note the limitation in that solution is, as said, that it works only with container which are template classes. And it does not work with `std::array` because the structure of array is [different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: You should add a note that it will not work with `std::array` or any non template containers.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I wrote that works with container which are template classes, but as you suggest, in order to be more clear I will add the negation's negation of the sentence